papr and transmit power
I am considering a transmission with bandwidth $B=4$ kHz and carrier frequency $f_c=20$ kHz.
If I have a PAPR $\in [9,10]$ dB, what should be my minimum transmit power? Is there a formula that gives the power as a function of the PAPR

By definition PAPR of a transmit signal $x[n]$ is given by $PAPR = \frac{\text{Max. Power}}{\text{Average power}} = \frac{\max_n |x[n]|^2}{\frac{1}{N}\sum_n |x[n]|^2}$ where $N$ is the njmber of samples in the transmit signal.

no power requirement arises from a PAPR. You are trying to get along without an understanding of the system you are to design. You will have to understand from what the PAPR in your specific system (which we can't know!) stems, and what problems that poses for the working of your system (we can't know that either).
